# In the GAE channel API, how high can duration_minutes be set?

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

I am implementing a Google App Engine app for which I need to create channels at a high rate. To avoid incurring excessive costs owing to the relatively stingy quota for channels, I am going to use the approach of [channel pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147221/best-method-of-channel-pooling-in-google-app-engine)

Since in this model, channels will be reused by future clients, I would like them to be as long lived as possible - up to 24 hours, which is the time after which quotas reset and extending a channel is no longer profitable. This seems straightforward:

```
        token = create_channel(clid, duration_minutes=1440)
```

...but I would like to know if the duration_minutes argument has an upper limit. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: I realized that the premise for this question is not entirely sound. I started implementing channel pooling since the free quota for channels is a measly 100. But it turns out that when you turn on billing, it grows massively. E.g. for $2/day you get ~100k channels. I will leave this question active nevertheless, in case someone decides to use this approach anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Argument duration_minutes must be less than 1441