# Can Google App Engine Channels be reused?

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

If a client disconnects from a Google App Engine channel, then can the service that created the channel reuse the corresponding token for another client?

I realize that there have been previous questions on the best way of "pooling channels" implicit in which is the idea that this is possible. However, I have also seen opinions that suggest that this is not possible. I would appreciate it if someone could clarify this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After about a week of debugging channel reuse, I upgraded myself to a premium App Engine account and asked the support team about whether this is possible. The answer was an unambiguous "no." You cannot reuse a token after having disconnected from it.